# Unsure about repeated error in Poisson GML offset model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, error, offset

am carrying out research to look at differences in fish density and fish species richness when using two different underwater visual census methods. My data was originally count data but then converted to fish density and so decided to use an offset using the following formula:

model1 <- glm(g_den ~ method + site + depth + offset(log(area)), poisson)

My 3 predictor variables are method, site and depth which I ordered as factors when I input them.

My response variables are grouper species richness, grouper density and the same for other fish groups.

Despite using the offset i keep getting the same error, could anyone advise me why this is?

In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.037500

Comment: You have already asked this question and got answers so why are you asking it again?

Comment: It's probably because you are still using the densities (`g_den`) as your response variable.